# Should I include Order "by column" to index?

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a query

```
select * from cp where customer_Id = ? order by date_created desc limit 1
```

I like to optimize execution of this query bu creating index for `customer_Id` column.

Question: should my index contain `date_created` column also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes.  If you can, include it as a descending column:

```
create index idx_cp_customerId_datecreated cp(customer_id, date_created desc)
```

Do note however:

- Some databases do not actually implement the `desc` option on indexes.
- Some databases will not use an ascending index for a descending sort
- This index will be no worse (for your query) than if you leave out `date_created`.